# UWP set lock screen image isn't working

Tags: c#, uwp, lockscreen

I am trying to set the lock screen background from my app. I'm using the following code:

```
var cachedPhotos = (await Photos.GetCachedPhotosAsync()).ToList();    // Get a list of Photo objects ({ "id": "12345.jpg", "url": "http://me.com/12345.jpg" }.
var newPhotos = (await Photos.GetAllPhotosAsync()).ToList();    // Ditto above comment.
var newPhotosList = ListHelpers.Merge(cachedPhotos, newPhotos);    // Merge the two lists.
await Photos.CachePhotosAsync(newPhotosList);    // Create a JSON file with a list of Photo objects. Also download each photo into the "photo_cache" folder.
var index = _random.Next(0, newPhotosList.Count - 1);
var photo = newPhotosList[index];

var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync($"{ApplicationData.Current.LocalCacheFolder.Path}\\photo_cache\\{photo.Id}");

if (await UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.Current.TrySetLockScreenImageAsync(file))
    Debug.WriteLine("Wallpaper set!");
else
    Debug.WriteLine("Wallpaper failed to set...");
```

The photo exists and is valid if I view it in File Explorer. My C# is getting the `StorageFile` correctly. But whenever I run `TrySetLockScreenImageAsync` it returns `false`. (Note that it *only* returns `false`, and not an `Exception` or anything that I can actually see what the problem is.) I'm using exactly what I found [here](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2015/11/uwp-lock-screen.html?utm_content=buffer4b5fa&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer), but I just can't get it to work. Is there another piece to this that I'm missing?

Comment: In the same link that you provided, it says you need to check first `UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.IsSupported()`. is it `true`?

Comment: @AVKNaidu Yes, it is true. Everything I have posted is wrapped in an `if` statement checking that condition.

Comment: Strange. Because without your `photo_cache` i tried it on my mobile it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so for some weird reason it seems that I have to do a `CopyAsync` on the `StorageFile` and copy it to `LocalFolder`, then use the newly copied file. Apparently it doesn't like the file coming from `LocalCacheFolder`.